# jquery link not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to insert multiple products and prices before submitting the main quotation form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<br>' + '<label>Product '+ counter + '  </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="product" id="product" value="" >' + 
          '<label>Price '+ counter + '  </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="price" id="price"  value="" >'+ '<a href="#" id="save" >Save!</a>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   
    counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
    });

    $("#save").click(function() {

        if(!$("#product").val() || !$("#price").val() ){
            apprise("You must define a product and price!");
            }else{
            var product = $("#product").val();
            var price = $("#price").val();
            var postdata = 'product='+product+'&price='+price;

            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "inserter/add_quotation_product.php",  
                data: postdata, 
                success: function() {  
                    $('#TextBoxesGroup').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html(product+" Saved!");  
                }  
            });  
            return false;  

        }
```

main html code:

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'> 
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1"> 
        <label>Product 1 </label> 
        <input type=text 
                id="product" 
                name="product" 
                placeholder="product to quote" 
                required/> 
        <label>Price 1</label> 
        <input id="price" 
                name="price" 
                type=text 
                placeholder="price of product" 
                required> 
            <a href="#" id="save" >Save!</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

the problem is clicking on the save button that is manually created works well but clicking the save button created by jquery seems be completely inactive!

Comment: this is the main html code:
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
  <label>Product 1 </label>
  <input type=text id="product" name="product" placeholder="product to quote" required/>
  <label>Price 1</label>
  <input id="price" name="price" type=text placeholder="price of product" required>
  <a href="#" id="save" >Save!</a>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: No code in comments, please; edit the question if you need to add additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event to the save link is already bound. When adding a new product you create a new save link without the event attached.

You can't have multiple elements links with the same id so I would assign a class to the save link. It must be in the main html code and in your javascript code that creates the link.

```
<a href="#" class="save">Save!</a>
```

Use the live method of the jquery object in order to bind the event for 'future' events as well. http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$(".save").live("click", function() {
});
```

Dependeding on the version of jquery you have to use on : http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: This worked well, you were right Albert, I had not inheriting the event to the future links! thank you so muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on()` method to delegate the click handler to your new buttons ( Instead of the deprecated `.live()` method) .

http://api.jquery.com/on

like:

```
$("#yourButtonParent").on('click', '#yourButton', function () {

    // code here

});
```